# How can I get ant behavior when expanding properties with gradle?

Tags: ant, properties, gradle

I have an ant project I'm converting to gradle.  In the ant project, there is something like this:

```
<copy todir="dest_dir">
  <fileset>
     ...
  </fileset>
  <filterchain>
    <expandproperties/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

The filter chain expands properties like `${property}`, but ignores dollar signs without braces.  I'm trying to replicate this behavior in gradle.

If I `expand` as below, gradle expands the files as a groovy template, which tries to expand dollar signs with braces.

```
copy {
   from 'source_dir'
   into 'dest_dir'
   expand(project.properties)
}
```

If I `filter` with the ant `ExpandProperties` filter class, I get a NullPointerException.  Is there an easy way to do this I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  The ExpandProperties filter needs its project property set with the Ant project.  This is how I got it configured to work:

```
copy {
    from 'source_dir'
    to 'dest_dir'
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ExpandProperties, project: ant.antProject)
}
```

This expands properties like `${property}` exactly the same as Ant, without getting tripped up on dollar signs without braces.